# Incorrect Tab Indicator on Support Libraries ViewPager / TabLayout when dynamically removing tabs

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, viewpagerindicator, android-tablayout

OK, I have been working with the new `Support Library`'s `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`, and in my app I am dynamically adding and removing tabs based on if the `SearchView` was opened/closed by the user.

**My implementation works; however, there appears to be a visual bug with the tab indicator. The correct tab fragment is displayed, but the tab indicator is under the wrong tab!!**

I did a lot of testing to see if this was my issue, but then figured it was a bug with the Support Library. I sent a [bug report to Google](https://goo.gl/eA8DZm), but the status of the report was marked as `userError.`

So the Google developer gave me an idea of what to do. I tried said fix; however, it didn't fix anything. In the last few hours, I did somemore indepth testing based on the fact that he said the correct behavior is dependant on if the `ViewPager`'s `OnPageChangedListener` is called.

I added extra info to my bug report, but since it was marked as userError, I don't know if the developer will respond. So I am on here now.

### Screen Recording

[Here is a screen recording of the issue](https://goo.gl/TKZzHR) *{NOTE: clicking this link will auto-download the screen recording **[.mp4]** }*. Take notice of the tab indicator. It should go to the previous displayed tab, but does not.

### Issues

### 1. Correct Indicator, wrong displayed fragment

```
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(final MenuItem item) {

        clearAllTabs();
        addTabs(displayedTabs);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(previousTabPosition, true);

        tabLayout.removeAllTabs();
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return true;

    }
```

**StackTrace:**

First go to 2nd tab, click SearchView, then close SearchView....

```
On MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener::onMenuItemActionCollapse(...)

    clearAllTabs()           [A, B, C, Search] -> []
    addTabs(displayedTabs)   [] -> [A, B, C]

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::OnPageSelected(2)
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::OnPageScrolled(2, 0.0, 0)

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true)

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageScrollStateChanged(2)
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageSelected(1)

    tabLayout.removeAllTabs()
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageSelected(0) [NOTE: this statement does not fire if Tab A was displayed before opening SearchView]

    return true

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageScrolled(0, 0.0, 0)

    // UI display is updated (Tab 1 fragment is displayed, but tab indicator is on 2nd Tab)

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageScrollStateChanged(0)
```

### 2. Correct Displayed Fragment, wrong tab indicator

```
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(final MenuItem item) {

        clearAllTabs();
        addTabs(displayedTabs);

        tabLayout.removeAllTabs();
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(previousTabPosition, true);

        return true;

    }
```

**StackTrace:**

First go to 2nd tab, click SearchView, then close SearchView....

```
On MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener::onMenuItemActionCollapse(...)
    clearAllTabs()           [A, B, C, Search] -> []
    addTabs(displayedTabs)   [] -> [A, B, C]

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::OnPageSelected(2)
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::OnPageScrolled(2, 0.0, 0)

    tabLayout.removeAllTabs()
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageScrollStateChanged(2)
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageSelected(0)

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true)

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageSelected(1)

    return true

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageScrolled(1, 0.0, 0)

    // UI display is updated (Tab 2 fragment is displayed, but tab indicator is on 3rd Tab)

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener::onPageScrollStateChanged(0)
```

### GitHub

Here is my [GitHub repo](https://goo.gl/yWVXA2)

- SearchView collapsing code [(Line 291)](https://goo.gl/n21AsM)
- [Custom FragmentPageAdapter](https://goo.gl/gyHHuF)

Comment: Can anyone replicate this? I did what the Google developer suggested, but it does not work. So I still think this is NOT userError.